# Windows Application That Displays Pop-Ups While Other Programs Are Running

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

Firstly, I have zero experience programming with .NET so this could be a pretty nooby question...

I'm wondering if it's possible to build an application like xFire - which displays pop-ups in-game to a user.

As the primary application will have focus, how does my application manage to display it's message/popup?  Does the primary application have to allow access or something?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As the primary application will have focus, how does my application manage to display it's message/popup? Does the primary application have to allow access or something?"

An application can set itself as "TopMost" which means it appears in front of other "normal" applications that are not TopMost.  A well behaved notification will appear without stealing focus from the current application (this is usually achieved with the ShowWindow() API and the SW_SHOWNA flag).  This does not require any permission from the currently active application.

Take a look at [TaskbarNotifier, a skinnable MSN Messenger-like popup in C# and now in VB.NET too](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3285/TaskbarNotifier-a-skinnable-MSN-Messenger-like-pop).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are looking for `NotifyIcon`, it displays little pop-ups just as know from Windows.
The example is a little long, but the documentation will surely help you understand.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu contextMenu1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem menuItem1;
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.contextMenu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
        this.menuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();

        // Initialize contextMenu1 
        this.contextMenu1.MenuItems.AddRange(
                    new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem[] {this.menuItem1});

        // Initialize menuItem1 
        this.menuItem1.Index = 0;
        this.menuItem1.Text = "E&xit";
        this.menuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuItem1_Click);

        // Set up how the form should be displayed. 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);
        this.Text = "Notify Icon Example";

        // Create the NotifyIcon. 
        this.notifyIcon1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(this.components);

        // The Icon property sets the icon that will appear 
        // in the systray for this application.
        notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("appicon.ico");

        // The ContextMenu property sets the menu that will 
        // appear when the systray icon is right clicked.
        notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = this.contextMenu1;

        // The Text property sets the text that will be displayed, 
        // in a tooltip, when the mouse hovers over the systray icon.
        notifyIcon1.Text = "Form1 (NotifyIcon example)";
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;

        // Handle the DoubleClick event to activate the form.
        notifyIcon1.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_DoubleClick);

    }

    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        // Clean up any components being used. 
        if( disposing )
            if (components != null)
                components.Dispose();            

        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }

    private void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object Sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Show the form when the user double clicks on the notify icon. 

        // Set the WindowState to normal if the form is minimized. 
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

        // Activate the form. 
        this.Activate();
    }

    private void menuItem1_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Close the form, which closes the application. 
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx).

Comment: Awesome! Can I customize the styling and sizing/offset of this icon? For example, if I wanted to place a black box in the top right corner, could I do that? Also, would this display if I were playing a game?

Comment: Possibly, but I am not sure. Have a look this line: `this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();` Check, if there is a container you might be able to add controls to.